# Pymongo search geo on line

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, geo

I have collection with geo coordinates. To find objects in circle I use command like this

```
collection.find({"loc":{"$within":{"$center":[[49.236484,28.472172], 10]}}})
```

But I need find objects on street(line)? how I can do that? And please tell me if my command will search right. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by **street**?

Comment: We have now idea about you structure or any info so how we are suppose to help you?

Comment: Part of object where I keep coordinates  
  "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            49.236484, 
            28.472172
        ]
    } 

I want to search objects in radius or near line(street)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a $polygon to make what is essentially a thick line?

```
collection.find({'loc':{'$within':{'$polygon':[[linestart_x, linestart_y], [linestart_x+jiggle, linestart_y+jiggle], [lineend_x, lineend_y], [lineend_x+jiggle, lineend_y+jiggle]]}}})
```

You'll have to experiment to find an appropriate number of the 'jiggle'.

Enjoy!